# reading data from flat file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, text-files, flat-file

i have flat files in some direcotry. each flat file contains around 60,000 rows of data. earlier we were using excel sheets to upload data. but now the challenge is it is taking more time to upload data into DB tables. can any body suggest me which is the best way to upload such a huge data into db tables. can we use SSIS for uploading data. if so, how can we achieve that. or please suggest me the feasible way. (effieciency of uploading data is main criteria here).

thanks,
murali

Answer (score 0):

Create a WCF service, call a method on it to queue the file request.
And the service should take care of reading the file and backing it to DB.

Comment: Create a WCF service, expose a contract (on wsHttpBinding) with QueueFileReadRequest method which takes in the filepath and invoke a method on threadpool thread. The method would read the file write it to Db. You could also use Async Programming model (i.e support Beingxxx and Endxxx methods). From ASP.NET application, add Service reference to the WCF service and make a call to the required WCF methods.